# How to replace NEWID() in sql script file with an actual random Guid?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, newid

So I have a huge script file that will inset loads and loads of data into my database, here is a sample.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SysCountry] ([country_id], [country_name]) VALUES (NEWID(), 'Argentina');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SysCountry] ([country_id], [country_name]) VALUES (NEWID(), 'Armenia');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SysCountry] ([country_id], [country_name]) VALUES (NEWID(), 'Aruba');
```

No I have 100s if not 1000s of NEWID() tags, however I need to re-use a alot of these ID's.  So I want to replace all NEWID() with an actual random GUID.  So the output would look like.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SysCountry] ([country_id], [country_name]) VALUES ('42FF2BE3-D2A7-4FD1-AAA9-6AA0FDBDDD28', 'Argentina');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SysCountry] ([country_id], [country_name]) VALUES ('59FF040C-5102-41D8-9F8B-782B42983F0E', 'Armenia');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SysCountry] ([country_id], [country_name]) VALUES ('7589B5F1-21C0-4EF8-897E-B8C7FF8EDFA9', 'Aruba');
```

I am using Notepad++ to write this, so maybe if you know a Regex I can use in the Find and Replace would be great.  Or if you know another way.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: In what way to you need to reuse the guids?

Comment: I need to use most of them again inside linking tables, but only in the script.

Comment: but obviously I don't want to go through each and everyone manually putting GUIDs into them

Comment: I know I will have to copy and paste them at a later date when I am creating the links.  But for now I would be good if I could just get them all replaced with actual guids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NEWID()` is actually a random GUID.

If you want to reuse it, e.g. when populating a child table, you can grab it again from the parent table, e.g. let's say you populate a country and then need to populate a state table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SysCountry] ([country_id], [country_name]) VALUES (NEWID(), 'Australia');

INSERT INTO [dbo].[SysState] ([state_id], [country_id], [state_name])
SELECT 
   NEWID(),
   (SELECT [country_id] FROM [dbo].[SysCountry] WHERE [country_name] = 'Australia'),
   'Victoria'
```

You can also use a local variable to do the same - the script will look better:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SysCountry] ([country_id], [country_name]) VALUES (NEWID(), 'Australia');

DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier
SELECT @id = [country_id] FROM [dbo].[SysCountry] WHERE [country_name] = 'Australia'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SysState] ([state_id], [country_id], [state_name])
    VALUES (NEWID(), @id, 'Victoria')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SysState] ([state_id], [country_id], [state_name])
    VALUES (NEWID(), @id, 'New South Wales')
```

Comment: Ok this is good, but is there a way to just simple replace NEWID() with a GUID?
I'll wait for a few more replies, but if I don't get any I will use this.

Comment: But NEWID() will give you a guid. What's wrong with the one it gives?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that, except I will need to re-use the guid over and over.  This answer is good, however still does require more coding.  
I just want to limit that,  but if its all I can do then I will do this.
But I would still prefer to just replace NEWID() with an actual ID

Comment: Ok, I get it. Let's see, maybe someone will have another idea.

Comment: I am using something called Roundhouse, I put new scripts all the time which will also be using these IDs,  NEWID would change the ID everytime, and I need it to stay the same